# Get the specific identifier in xml code with php

Tags: php, xml

Good day,
I'm trying to get a specific value of an XML file in this example I need to get a 
productidentifier in each product that has the tag `<b221>` set to 03 something like this:

```
<productidentifier><b221>03</b221><b244>9783672461027</b244></productidentifier>
```

where I can get then the `<b244>` tag to store the EAN.

The problem is that specific items have sometimes more then one productidentifier for example:

```
<productidentifier><b221>02</b221><b244>3672461024</b244></productidentifier>
<productidentifier><b221>03</b221><b244>9783672461027</b244></productidentifier>
```

So far I tried to use:

```
    foreach ($xml->product as $item) {
            $item->productidentifier->b221
    }
```

Which will always return me the first productidenfitier in the list

```
    foreach ($xml->product as $item) {
                $identifier = $item->productidentifier->xpath('//productidentifier');
                dd($identifier);
    }
```

Which returns me all the product identifiers in the list: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq0NE.png

How to do it?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to extend your XPath expression to include a check that the `<b221>` element is `03`.  This code searches for these and outputs the `<b244>` value

```
foreach  ( $xml->xpath('//productidentifier[b221="03"]') as $product )    {
    echo $product->b244.PHP_EOL;
}
```